# Bootstrap not mounting EBS volume

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, amazon-ebs

I'm running the following when Bootstrapping an Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
mkdir /vol01
echo "/dev/xvdf /vol01 auto noatime 0 0" | tee –a /etc/fstab
mount /vol01
```

It formats the partition but doesn't run steps 2/3.  I'm not finding any errors in the logs.  I'm selecting /dev/sdf as a second EBS volume.  I have no issues running the 2nd/3rd commands once I login to the server.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "bootstrapping?" Are you using cloud-init?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Answer (score 0):

In cloud init, if any of the steps fails (i.e. returns an error exit code), the rest of the steps will not be performed. My guess would be that the `tee` fails and as a result also the `mount` isn't executed.

It would be helpful if you mention how exactly are you using cloud-init: is it using a cloud-config file with `runcmd`, or are you using a script?